# Exporting remote Android Service as jar

Tags: android, android-service

I don't know if i'm doing it right or not.
I created a service importing the android.jar library file. and then created my own jar of that service.
Now when i include this jar file in anyother android project, adds its entry in manifest, starts it with

```
startService(new intent(getApplicationContext(),MyService.class));
```

Nothing happens.It doest not starts and no errors/warning :s 
What i'm trying to achieve is that: creating a library of my service which i can easily use in many of my other apps or distribute it to other vendors to embed in their apps easily. Tell if i'm doing it right or suggest any other way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will still need to add the service to your manifest of the application.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html

```
<service android:enabled=["true" | "false"]
     android:exported=["true" | "false"]
     android:icon="drawable resource"
     android:label="string resource"
     android:name="com.package.name.services.MyService" >
. . .
</service>
```

If in a lib project or jar, I would try/recommend full package names

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks chris for fast response but no success. `<service android:name=".MyService" android:process=":remote"
   android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
  </service>`

Comment: i have `Log.e("tag","service started");` in oncreate of service which never appeared in logcat

Comment: Yes it fixed it, Thanks Chris. My service was in some package so i have to use the complete name. with `.` it was looking for the service in the same package as of client activity. Thanks again

Comment: No problem, if you have activities in a library project, I recommend the same too.